# R saving the output of table() into a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3,4,4,2,2)
period<-c("first","calib","valid","valid","calib","first","valid","valid","calib","first","calib","valid")
df<-data.frame(id,period)
```

typing

```
table(df)
```

results in

```
period
id  calib first valid
1     1     2     0
2     2     0     2
3     0     0     2
4     1     1     1
```

however if I save it as a data frame 'df'

```
 df<-data.frame(table(df))
```

the format of 'df' would be like

```
id period Freq
1   1  calib    2
2   2  calib    1
3   3  calib    1
4   4  calib    0
5   1  first    1
6   2  first    2
7   3  first    0
8   4  first    0
9   1  valid    0
10  2  valid    0
11  3  valid    2
12  4  valid    3
```

how can I avoid this and how can I save the first output as it is into a data frame?

more importantly is there any way to get the same result using 'dcast'?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Would this help?

```
> data.frame(unclass(table(df)))
  calib first valid
1     1     2     0
2     2     0     2
3     0     0     2
4     1     1     1
```

Comment: now another question: what if I want the id column to be included in the resulted data frame?

Comment: The answer to your question @AliCivil is:
````df$id <- row.names(df)````

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate just a little bit.  I've changed the ids in the example data.frame such that your ids are not 1:4, in order to prove that the ids are carried along into the table and are not a sequence of row counts.

```
id <- c(10,20,30,40,10,10,20,30,40,40,20,20)    
period <- c("first","calib","valid","valid","calib","first","valid","valid","calib","first","calib","valid")
df <- data.frame(id,period)
```

Create the new data.frame one of two ways.  [rengis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603625/rengis) answer is fine for 2-column data frames that have the id column first.  It won't work so well if your data frame has more than 2 columns, or if the columns are in a different order.

Alternative would be to specify the columns and column order for your table:

```
df3 <- data.frame(unclass(table(df$id, df$period)))
```

the `id` column is included in the new data.frame as `row.names(df3)`.  To add it as a new column:

```
df3$id <- row.names(df3)
df3
   calib first valid id
10     1     2     0 10
20     2     0     2 20
30     0     0     2 30
40     1     1     1 40
```