# R is it possible to get the output of table() using dcast?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3,4,4,2,2)
period<-c("first","calib","valid","valid","calib","first","valid","valid","calib","first","calib","valid")
df<-data.frame(id,period)
```

typing

```
table(df)
```

results in

```
period
id  calib first valid
1     1     2     0
2     2     0     2
3     0     0     2
4     1     1     1
```

Is there any way to get the same result using 'dcast' and save it as a new data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, id ~ period, length)
Using period as value column: use value.var to override.
  id calib first valid
1  1     1     2     0
2  2     2     0     2
3  3     0     0     2
4  4     1     1     1
```

You can also type just `dcast(df, id ~ period)` and `length` will be chosen by default too. As I can see, you tried to find this out in your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591445/r-saving-the-output-of-table-into-a-data-frame). Extended solution without `dcast` would look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(unclass(table(df)))
df$ID <- rownames(df)
df
  calib first valid ID
1     1     2     0  1
2     2     0     2  2
3     0     0     2  3
4     1     1     1  4
```